# JAVAFX Column Not Populating String

Tags: java, fxml

I have a column tied to an observable list that will not display the String component of the underlying object but will display the numbers. I do not see how this is possible. Here is my code.

Product Class

```
public class Product {

    private String  name;
    private double  quantity;
    private double  cost;

    public Product(String name, double quantity, double cost) 
    {
        this.name     = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.cost     = cost;
    }
}
```

Main Controller

```
public class MainMenuController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Product> tblReceipt;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> colName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> colQuantity;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> colPrice;

    private double total;

    private final ObservableList<Product> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Product("Steak", 1, 2.00), new Product("Eggs", 3, 5.00));


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
           tblReceipt.setEditable(false);
           colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
           colQuantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
           colPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cost"));
           tblReceipt.setItems(data);

    }
```

FXML

```
  <TableView fx:id="tblReceipt" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="227.0">
<columns>
  <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Item" />
  <TableColumn fx:id="colQuantity" prefWidth="75.0" text="Quantity" />
  <TableColumn fx:id="colPrice" prefWidth="75.0" text="Price" />
</columns>
```

I get the error from scene builder that there is no injectable field for colName which is the problem. However, it is clearly there.

Comment: please post the error, with stack trace, that will help others to help you.

Comment: And also post the **.FXML** file so we can help (:

Comment: step ahead of ya there. Thanks yall.

Comment: JavaFX 8 recommends NOT using the `initialize(URL,ResourceBundle)` and to instead use an annotated no-arg `initialize()` method

Comment: Your table column name is "item" in the fxml, not "name", or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: The stack trace says the error occurred at line 61.  Which line of your code is line 61?

Comment: Tried the changes mentioned below. Same errors.

Comment: Itbworks now, but still doesn't display "eggs". I'm assuming this has something to do with it being a String?

Comment: colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

Comment: <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Item" />

Answer (score 0):

The `tblReceipt` has a column named `colItem`, not `colName`.  Try fixing that and see where you get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is so simple preciously in this line

```
colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

You did't tied it with the **FXML** file

open the **Scene Builder** and set the `colName` id

Hope this is the solution